# HttpResponseMessage does not fetch non-ascii letters

Tags: c#

http://localhost:8021/Documents?attachmentId=02D4FF48C80D1EEB8DC46D2C443C1E93&integrationType=MyService

Following the link above I will directly download a `txtFile_æøå.txt`

However, I was hoping the following code would do the same, and be able to find the filename.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponse(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient cl = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage resp = cl.GetAsync(url).Result)
        {
            var byteArray = resp.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I was hoping result would contain `txtFile_æøå.txt`, but it simply returns 'text'. Does anyone know why I cannot fetch the filename when it contains non-ascii characters? Seems to work when I am only using ascii characters.

Comment: I don't see you getting the filename in this code, is it missing something?

Comment: To debug output the individual bytes in the byte array.  You should discover that it's not a UTF-8 encoding of that string.

Comment: The code has more problems than just the filename. Why use `.Result` in an `async` method? You aren't retrieving the filename anywhere. Finally, if you want the contents as a string, use `ReadAsStringAsync()`. This will convert the payload to a string using the correct encoding specified in the response's headers. What you did will mangle the contents if the encoding isn't US-ASCII or UTF8